# utilizar variable .loc en pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib

estoy utilizando el modulo PANDAS y al momento de utilizar la etiqueta .loc me responde error, aquí coloco el código con un archivo .csv (distri_sism_1.csv):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


datos = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin1")

df1 = datos.loc[datos['REGION'] == 'LORETO']
print (df1)
```

Acá coloco el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\Sales_Solubles.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1622, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'REGION'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/proyectos_python/zona_sism/archivo_sismo/cod_prueba_sism.py", line 28, in <module>
    df1 = datos.loc[datos['REGION'] == 'LORETO']
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\Sales_Solubles.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\Sales_Solubles.py\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1622, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'REGION'
```

Quiero saber que estoy haciendo mal en el código para trabajar con PANDAS

Al colocar el código `print(datos.columns)`:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\Sales_Solubles.py\python.exe "C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/proyectos_python/zona_sism/archivo_sismo/cod_prueba_sism.py"
Index(['REGION;PROVINCIA;DISTRITO;ZONASISMICA'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Parece que tu tabla no tiene una columna llamada "REGION". Por otro lado no haría falta `.loc` en este caso.

Comment: En pantalla s hay una columna REGION, que codigo utilizaria para este caso?

Comment: A lo mejor el nombre de la columna lleva espacios o caracteres "raros". Prueba a volcar los nombres de las columnas que pandas ha leido haciendo un `print(datos.columns)` y muestra qué te sale (preferiblemente editando la pregunta y no en un comentario, para que se vea mejor)

Comment: He colocado el codigo de abajo y me responde todos los encabezados, el encabezado REGION si existe. 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datos = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin1")


print(datos.columns)


df1 = datos.loc[(datos['REGION'] == 'LORETO')]

Pregunto si sera un error de codificación de caracteres del archivo .csv

Comment: Gracias Miguel, pero te había pedido que incluyeras esa información en la pregunta, en vez de en un comentario, pues en el comentario se lee muy mal. Además, te había pedido también que pegaras en la pregunta lo que te sale en ese `print(datos.columns)` pues es posible que yo pueda ver algo que tú estés pasando por alto. Tienes un enlace "editar" debajo de la pregunta para modificarla y añadirle información

Comment: Gracias @abulafia, ya lo edité; disculpa no había entendido bien tu pegunta.

Comment: ¿Ves? Pues ahora ya se ve el problema. Tu tabla tiene una sola columna que lleva por nombre "REGION;PROVINCIA;DISTRITO;ZONASISMICA" así, todo junto. Es decir, el lector csv ha fallado al leer tu documento y separarlo por columnas porque por defecto espera que el separador sea la coma, pero en tu caso es el punto y coma. Añade el parámetro `sep=";"` a la llamada a `read_csv()`.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia.... Excelente... Ese era el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar el prolema, este es la solucion.  @abufalia

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

    opcion_z_sismica = input("ingrese la opcion: ")
```